# jQuery : find and wrap textnode with some element

Tags: jquery, textnode

my HTML code :

```
<body>Firebrand will tend to burn any bricks out there. so the best idea is to ignore any active firebrand if you are a bricks. Otherwise, you can challenge a firebrand if you have the proper quality to keep up with their latest technology. And don't mess up with firebrand if you are a robber.</body>
```

I want to find any "firebrand" inside the body and replace it with `<span class="firebrand">firebrand</span>` with jQuery

Comment: Please articulate your intention more clearly. As you can see in the answer of Karim79 the specification isn't clear enough.

Comment: sorry my bad,

I just want to find any keyword I desire to be wrapped with span regardless the parent element, it should search in the whole document.

I need to get the text node and wrap it up with span, so I can give a different style.

is there anyway I can do this without using $(selector).html() ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just recurse through the DOM, while using:

`.replace(/(firebrand)/gi, '<span class="firebrand">$1</span>')`

on each text content.

```
function firebrand($el) {
   $el.contents().each(function () {

       if (this.nodeType == 3) { // Text only
           $(this).replaceWith($(this).text()
               .replace(/(firebrand)/gi, '<span class="firebrand">$1</span>'));
       } else { // Child element
           firebrand($(this));
       }

   });
}

firebrand($("body"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following.

```
var textApply;
textApply = function(node){
  jQuery.map($(node), function(node) {
    var value = $(node)[0];
    if (value.nodeType == 3 && value.textContent.match(/firebrand/gi)) {
      var foo = value.textContent.replace(/[\n\r\t ]+/,' ').replace(/firebrand/gi, '<span style="color:red">Firebrand</span>');
      var newitem = $(foo);
      $(node).replaceWith(newitem);
    } else if (value.nodeName != 'SCRIPT') {
      jQuery.map($(node).contents(), textApply);
    }
  });
};
textApply($('body'));
```