# Find Characters and wrap with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to find `//` (slashes) in the document and wrap it with a `span`.

I've tried

```
var slashes = "//";
/slashes+/
```

So output should be:

```
Hello There! I Am <span class="slashes">//</span> An Alien
```

With jQuery `.replace()` and `:contains` but nothing happens, and I am new to reguler expressions to do this correctly. How would I do this?

Edit: What have I tried:
[Solution for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788939/jquery-find-and-wrap-textnode-with-some-element) didn't work:

```
function slashes($el) {

   $el.contents().each(function () {
       dlbSlash = "//";
       if (this.nodeType == 3) { // Text only
           $(this).replaceWith($(this).text()
               .replace(/(dlbSlash)/gi, '<span class="slashes">$1</span>'));
       } else { // Child element
           slashes($(this));
       }

   });
}

slashes($("body"));
```

Comment: oh wow, g'luck, this requires a char search and replace within index values and blah blah blah .... g'luck!

Comment: The regexp would be /\/\//g, however it's going to take a lot more than a simple .replace.

Comment: How about sharing your current attempt(s) on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: If you use an external string to build a regex, you need to doubly escape the text, and then build a an explicit RegExp object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the slashes in your regex. Try

```
var mystring = "adjfadfafdas//dsagdsg//dsafda"
mystring.replace(/\/\//g,'<span class="slashes">\/\/</span>');
```

Should output

```
"adjfadfafdas<span class="slashes">//</span>dsagdsg<span class="slashes">//</span>dsafda"
```

If you want to replace the slashes in h2 and p tags, you can loop through them like so:

```
$('h2, p').each(function(i, elem) { 
    $(elem).text(
        $(elem).text().replace(/\/\//g,'<span class="slashes">\/\/</span>'));
});
```

This will blow away any additional html tags you may have had in your p and h2 tags, though.

Comment: If it helps, there wouldn't be any chars next to the slashes.

Comment: So how would I do this for the whole document? Mainly in h2 and p elements

Comment: $('h2, p').each(function(i, elem) {
   $(elem).text($(elem).text().replace(/\/\//g,'<span class="slashes">\/\/</span>'));
});

Comment: Select each one and loop through them would be the safest way.

Comment: Using this method, the HTML renders as text and shown on the page.

Comment: Nevermind. Replaced .text() with .html() and worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is one more way of doing this

```
//Find html inside element with id content
var html = $('#content').html();
//Replace // with <span style='color:red'>//</span>
html = html.replace(/\/{2}/g,"<span style='color:red'>$&</span>");
//Return updated html back to DOM
$('#content').html(html);​
```

and here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CNFdC/1/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you were looking in the right place. The only thing to fix is your regular expression:

```
.replace(/\/\//g, '<span class="slashes">$1</span>'));
```

Focusing on text nodes (type 3) is important, instead of doing a global replace of the body innerHTML that might break your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply such replacement for single `//` only, go with

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(\/{2})/g, "<span class=\"slashes\">$1</span>");
```

However if you want to apply that for 2 or more slashes, then use

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/(\/{2,})/g, "<span class=\"slashes\">$1</span>");
```

But if you want to apply it for any even quantity of slashes (e.g. `//`, `////`, etc.) then you need to use

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/((?:\/{2})+)/g, "<span class=\"slashes\">$1</span>");
```

Test the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zKBAr/).